# Update results in failed DB check

Tags: upgrade

In trying to upgrade to Civi 4.6.3, I did a backup using Drupal 7.35 (I know, updating that was next) Backup and Migrate, then copied the Civi code files to my desktop, deleted the old Civi, copied in the new Civi, and got an error message that says "Database check failed - the database looks to have been partially upgraded. You may want to reload the database with the backup and try the upgrade process again."
So I did that, using both the backup I had just made and a previous one. Same error message both times. In delving into the Advanced Settings on B&M, it appears that the default only backs up the Civi database. I modified it (I think) to backup the Drupal database as well, backed up the whole site (with the reportedly incomplete database), hoping that what was "incomplete" was the Drupal portion. Same error message every time I start Civi.
What can I do, short of asking my ISP to restore the whole site to a time when I wasn't messing with it (I'm even more ignorant with MySQL). 
I know it advises always trying updates on a development site first, but my desktop is Windows and the ISP is Linux. IF I have to, I'll upgrade my contract to give me another site, but I'd probably run into the same problem there.
Civi seems to work just fine, but there is that disturbing error message and I am disturbed enough as it is.
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure the problem isn't already on the "old" site?

Could you try to (without changing any code) go to the civicrm upgrade page on the old site (/civicrm/upgrade). do **not** upgrade, just look at what's on the screen

Do you have a message saying you are already at the correct version and nothing to be done?

```
Sorry but we are not able to provide this at the moment.
Your database has already been upgraded to CiviCRM [your version]
```

... or do you already have a message saying database check failed?

If the later, it means that you had a partial update already that was never properly sorted. It's recoverable, but you might have to dig into sql more than you'd like (or hire an expert to help you, probably an easier option to help you untangle the situation)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. The actual codebase update seems to have worked. I also had gotten a (fleeting) message about some problem involving InnoDB, so maybe it was a MySQL configuration problem. I think I am just going to export the Contacts list (the only thing that has changed much lately) to .csv and ask my very-forgiving ISP to reload the DB from backup.  Incidentally, I learned in trying to figure out what went wrong that Drupal's Backup and Migrate module's default settings only backed up the Civi DB and not the separate Drupal DB. So maybe that is the problem. Thanks again.

Comment: mff, "Database check failed - the database looks to have been partially upgraded." doesn't sound good to me. Ignoring it is going to be biting you in your whatever part of your body you don't want to at the next upgrade I'm afraid...

Comment: After messing around with WP, I'm back to Drupal and trying to test the idea of exporting the Contacts data to CSV, then loading a backup from back before the glitch occurred (which may lose a lot of Contact data) and then importing the CSV. My ISP may be able to selectively restore the DB, but I want to have the Import option in case he can't. The problem right now is that the Civi Contacts Import screen on my desktop version will not accept the Contacts exported from the on-line version. It lets me browse and specify the CSV I downloaded, but when I hit "Continue", it throws an error message